# Change font size of selected captions

Tags: captions, fontsize

Caption font size can be changed globally using

```
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
```

However, suppose I need only one/two captions' fontsize be changed, not all. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Just out of curiosity: *Why* do you need to change the font sizes of selected captions? Are the captions in question very long and take up too much space? If that's the case, do consider shortening the captions and placing the excised material in the body of the associated floats. Captions work best, as far as most readers will confirm, if they're concise.

Comment: I am preparing a Beamer presentation, and it so happens that an image grid of 3x2 cannot be accommodated along with the captions in the default size..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change caption setup locally with the `\captionsetup` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{First caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{font={Large,it}}
\caption{Second caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Third caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: From the documentation: "It’s good to know that `\captionsetup` has an effect on the current environment only. So if you want to change settings for the current figure or table only, just place the `\captionsetup` command inside the figure or table right before the `\caption` command."